# How to find kernel and range of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Consider L:Pn→Pn given by L(p)=p''. What is the kernel of L? What is its range? What are the dimensions of the kernel and the range?

For kernel i think i'm supposed to set 
p''=0 
so that would mean that
p'=c, where c∈R, and then 
p=cp right?
so kerL={cp:c∈R} ?

for range i'm really not sure what to do

and for dimension i know that it is the number of elements in the basis of the Vector Space, what vector space is that?

Answer (score 0):

For the kernel, you're close - note that $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}(2) = 0$ as well.
The full kernel is:
$$\ker L = \{a+bx\mid a,b\in\mathbb R\}$$
This means that the kernel is generated by the basis vectors $\{1,x\}$.
It follows that the range is generated by the basis vectors $\{x^2,x^3,\dots,x^n\}$
So, the range will be the span of this image.  Now, note that $L(x^n) = n(n-1)x^{n-2}$.  So, the image will be spanned by:
$$\{2,6x,\dots, n(n-1)x^{n-2}\}$$
As the constants don't really matter for this, we have that the image is precisely $P_{n-2}(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: wait is so is the image the range? where did {x2,x3,…,xn} come from?

Comment: The image is the range.  We have that $\{1,x,x^2,\dots,x^n\}$ is a basis for $P_n(\mathbb R)$.  Of these, $\{1,x\}$ generate the kernel.  The rest get sent into the image.